# Crop images by x,y,w,h

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop

I want to crop images ..
I get the x,y,w,h data by `JCrop` plugin ..
So i want just to know if is there any technique to crop the image in javascript based on my (`x,y,w,h`) data .
Thank you .

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? What about searched for examples? No one is going to just write your code for you.

Comment: I want just to know if it's possible by js or i have to search for an other plugin to do this

Comment: Yes it's possible in JS. Plugins do not change what's possible with JS. In fact, jQuery plugins are written in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried getImageData? See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas#Getting_the_pixel_data_for_a_context

Comment: To use this .. i have to download an external library ? or it's included in js ?